Blobs not being cleared when using Playwright
Noticed while testing that blobs aren't being cleared as they should be when using Playwright.
Tried a simple test using https://maps.google.com (as it uses blobs), and I'm checking chrome://blob-internals to see the blob count.
Without Playwright, the blob count is no more than 1 after about 30 seconds.
Whereas there are multiple active blobs even after a minute when the browser is launched using Playwright.
Unable to find why this happens as I'm not really seeing any errors anywhere.
import { chromium } from "@playwright/test";

( async () => {
  let options = {
    headless: false
  }

  const browser = await chromium.launch(options);
  const context = await browser.newContext();

  const mapsPage = await context.newPage();
  mapsPage.goto('https://maps.google.com');

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000 * 60));
  
  const blobsPage = await context.newPage();
  blobsPage.goto('chrome://blob-internals');

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000 * 30));

  await browser.close();
})();


Don't forget to await your goto calls. If you want them to resolve quickly, use {waitUntil: "commit"}. You can also import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises", and avoid timeouts anyway in favor of precise predicates. What difference does it make whether there are a few active blobs or not? Are you controlling for the browser when running your tests (i.e. use the same test browser as a human)?

@ggorlen
Thanks for the correction and tips.
What difference does it make whether there are a few active blobs or not?
We were expecting a callback from FinalizationRegistry to make sure we've cleaned up, but that isn't happening.
